# Web RTC navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I've enabled chrome://flags/#enable-usermedia-screen-capture and restarted chrome, attempting to share video -

However, when I attempt to stream via `navigator.getUserMedia` I get a permission denied error. I have read this can only be enabled via https - is this true?

Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/lfender6445/11357060

Update: In order to share screens (not your video camera) it appears you have to be hosting via https.

Comment: Hi, how does your code look like? I have been using `getUserMedia` without https.

Comment: You could try to put `$('#share_screen').click(function() {.. if (navigator.getUserMedia) {}` around the function after setting the variable to see if it really got bind.

Comment: i don't think thats the issue as I am able to clearly see the error once I have clicked. You said you have this working without ssl? Can I see an example?

Comment: I used this : http://peerjs.com/examples last time. There are some examples. http://cdn.peerjs.com/demo/videochat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this : peerjs.com/examples last time. There are some examples. cdn.peerjs.com/demo/videochat.

You are welcome.